# How do I disable "ajax partial page loads" in Viewflow?

Tags: django-viewflow

I notice that Viewflow has an optimization that when you click a link in the Sidebar (and a few other places) it doesn't do a regular full page load, but appears to do an AJAX request for the target page, and dynamically replaces the  element with the  element from the result.

This breaks some of my code, but I haven't been able to find where in the Viewflow codebase this is implemented.

1) Where in the viewflow codebase is the code located that adds a click handler for links and overrides them with an Ajax request.

2) Is there a recommended way to disable this feature for specific pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewflow uses Turbolinks to speed up page loading and provide SPA-like UX for a user.

The recommended way for custom javascript is to wrap the code into standard web component - http://docs.viewflow.io/material_frontend.html#custom-components